# Preserving sessions

Tags: jakarta-ee, stateful-session-bean

I have to develop an application with Java EE which will contain users and some data specific to this users persisted in a database.
I am now learning Web development with Java so I would like to ask if it correct to hold the logged in user id in a stateful session bean and then inject this stateful bin in a stateless one which will contain the methods which update and retrieve these data based on the id taken from the stateful bean?